# ReactJS - put overflown elements into a "..." dropdown button

Tags: javascript, html, dom, reactjs

I have following UI element on the top of my page:

```
|[Static1] [Dynamic1] [Dynamic2] [Dynamic3]                [Static2]|
```

So `Static1` is some logo component that sticks to the left, `Static2` is some user menu component that sticks to the right.

Now inside of it I have a collection component that displays several dynamic elements loaded from the DB.

All is good, if there are not too much of those components, but if there are more, I don't wan't any linebreaks, only some fort of "More" menu, something like:

```
|[Static1] [Dynamic1] [Dynamic2] [Dynamic3] [Dynamic4][...][Static2]|
```

and when I click the `[...]` button I wan't a vertical list of the dynamic components.

The list of dynamic items is stored in an `ElementList` component, with following code:

```
React.createClass({
    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="listparent">
                { this.props.elements.map((element) => {
                    return <Element
                        ref={"element-"+element.name}
                        key={element.name}
                    })}
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

`this.props.elements` is a collection passed as a prop. I tried something allong those lines, but it either didn't work or worked but not on each page refresh:

```
export default React.createClass({
        getInitialState(){
            return {
                visibleElements: this.props.elements,
                hiddenElements: []
            }
        },
        componentDidMount() {
            this.rearrange();
        },
        componentDidUpdate(){
            this.rearrange();
        },
        rearrange(){
            var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.listparent);
            let visibleElements = [];
            let hiddenElements = [];
            for(var i=0; i< this.props.elements.length; i++)
            {
                var currentElement = this.props.elements[i];
                var domElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["element-"+element.name]);
                if(domElement) {
                    if (domElement.offsetTop + domElement.offsetHeight >
                        element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight ||
                        domElement.offsetLeft + domElement.offsetWidth >
                        element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth - 200) {
                        hiddenElements.push(currentElement);
                    }
                    else {
                        visibleElements.push(currentElement);
                    }
                }
            }
            if(this.state.visibleElements.length != visibleElements.length) {
                this.setState({
                    visibleElements: visibleElements,
                    hiddenElements: hiddenElements
                })
            }
        },
        render() {
            return (
                <div ref="listparent">
                    { this.state.visibleElements.map((element) => {
                        return <Element
                            ref={"element-"+element.name}
                            key={element.name} />
                        })}
                    { this.state.hiddenElements.length >0 &&
                            <DropdownMenu
                                Header="..."
                            >
                                { this.state.hiddenElements.map((element) => {
                                    return <Element
                                        ref={"element-"+element.name}
                                        key={element.name} />
                                    })}
                            </DropdownMenu>
                    }
                </div>
            )
        }
    });
```

Here is a rough jsFiddle with what I want to do: https://jsfiddle.net/3uf9r8ne/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working, I don't know if that's the best solution, or how robust it is, but works for me at least for now.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1w6m1n6h/

```js
var Dropdown = React.createClass({
    getInitialState(){
      return {
          isOpen: false
      }
    },
    componentWillMount() {
        document.addEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
    },
    componentWillUnmount() {
        document.removeEventListener('click', this.handleClick, false);
    },
    handleClick: function (e) {
        var component = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.component);
        if (e.target == component || $(component).has(e.target).length) {
            // Inside the component
        }
        else{
            // Outide
            this.setState({ isOpen: false});
        }
    },
    render()
    {
        return (
          <div ref="component" className="dropdown">
              <div className="dropdown-button" onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen : !this.state.isOpen})}>{this.props.Header}</div>
              {
                    this.state.isOpen && (
                        <div className="dropdown-menu"  onClick={() => this.setState({ isOpen : false})}>
                            {React.Children.map(this.props.children, (item) => item)}
                        </div>
                        )
              }
          </div>
        );
    }
});

var Card = React.createClass({
  render() {
    let className = "card";
    if(this.props.isHidden)
       className += " is-hidden";
    return (
      <div className={className}>{this.props.name}</div>
    )
  }
});

var Cards = React.createClass({
 getInitialState() {
   return {
      vCards: [],
        hCards: [],
        lastSetCards: [],
        preMounted: false,
        laidOut: false
    };
 },
 rearrange() {
   _.throttle(this.setState({laidOut: false, preMounted: false}), 100);
 },
   componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('resize', this.rearrange);
  },
  componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('resize', this.rearrange);
  },
 componentDidUpdate() {
    if(this.props.cards.length != this.state.lastSetCards || !this.state.preMounted) {
     
     this.setState({
                lastSetCards: this.props.cards.length,
                vCards: this.props.cards,
                preMounted: true,
                laidOut: false
                });
    }
    if(this.state.preMounted && !this.state.laidOut) {
         var element = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.listparent);
        let visibleCards = [];
        let hiddenCards = [];
        for(var i=0; i< this.props.cards.length; i++)
        {
            var card = this.props.cards[i];
            var cardElement = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs["card-"+card]);
            if(cardElement) {
                if (cardElement.offsetTop + cardElement.offsetHeight >
                    element.offsetTop + element.offsetHeight ||
                    cardElement.offsetLeft + cardElement.offsetWidth >
                    element.offsetLeft + element.offsetWidth - 160) {
                    hiddenCards.push(card);
                }
                else {
                    visibleCards.push(card);
                }
            }
        }
        this.setState({
          vCards: visibleCards,
            hCards: hiddenCards,
            laidOut: true
        });
    }
 },
 render() {
     return (<div className="cards-top" ref="listparent">
         <div className="cards" >
            {this.state.vCards.map((c)=> <Card ref={"card-"+c} key={c} name={c} />)}
            </div>
            <Dropdown Header="MORE">
            {this.state.hCards.map((c)=> <Card isHidden={true} key={c} name={c} />)}
            </Dropdown>
            </div>
            )
 }
});

var Hello = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
      return {
      cards: ["one", "two" ]
                };
    },
    componentDidMount() {
      this.setState({
          cards: ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight",
            "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen"]
        });
    },
    render: function() {
      let addNew = () => { 
           this.state.cards.push("additional_"+this.state.cards.length);
              this.setState({
                cards: this.state.cards
              })
     };
        return (
        <div>
        <div className="header">
          <div className="logo">Logo</div>
            <div className="user">User</div>
            <Cards cards={this.state.cards} />
            <div className="clear"></div>
        </div>
        <br/><br/>
        <button onClick={addNew}>Add</button>
        </div>);
    }
});
 
ReactDOM.render(
 <Hello name="World" />,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```css
.logo
{
  float: left;
    margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.user
{
  float: right;
    margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.header{
  position: relative;
  max-height: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.cards
{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.clear
{
  clear: both;
}

.card
{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}

.cards-top
{
   display: block;  
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
    border: green 1px solid;
}

.dropdown
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.is-hidden
{
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-button
{
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```